# Access to mysql database does not work anymore after php upgrade

Tags: php, macos

I upgraded my installed php 5.3.15 to 5.4.16 on (my mac osx lion) using the link http://php-osx.liip.ch/. (and did not nothing else afterwards; I checked the new installed version by means of phpinfo().

When I load a developed html page in the browser I noticed that the page does not load specific information from my (local mysql) database anymore (I can still access the database by means of phpMyAdmin.) Entering the command php -v still shows the old php version 5.3.15. Prior to the php upgrade my developed html page worked fine.

Is there a setting I have forgotten with the upgrade? Any suggestions?

Thank you for your help in advance (ps: I'm just a beginner and not very familiar with these kind of installations).

Answer (score 0):

According to the link you posted, the installer adds a new php.ini file located at:

/usr/local/php5/php.d/99-liip-developer.ini

The php.ini file specifies the location of the mysql socket file. If this directive is not set properly in the new php.ini file you will not be able to connect to the DB. I would suggest copying the mysql default socket settings from the old php.ini file to the new one. Please keep in mind that there are mulitple default socket settitngs for mysql, mysqli, and pdo.

Comment: thnx for your comment (!).However, the installer has NOT installed a php.ini file at /usr/local/php5/php.d/99-liip-developer.ini. In fact, 99-liip-developer.ini is an ini file (not a directory...) (as I just checked). It includes the setting 'mysql.default_socket = /tmp/mysql.sock'. (thick beginner question:) how do I locate the old php.ini file? (fyi, in installed the previous php 5.3.15 using the instructions at http://coolestguyplanettech.com/downtown/install-and-configure-apache-mysql-php-and-phpmyadmin-osx-108-mountain-lion

Comment: I believe the default php.ini location for the the PHP install bundled with OSX is /usr/local/php/php.ini. For more information see this: http://php.net/manual/en/install.macosx.bundled.php

Comment: thnx for the comment. using phpinfo() shows that the new php.ini file is in the dir /usr/local/php5/lib and this php.ini file included "mysql.default_socket = " (so no reference). I changed that to "mysql.default_socket = /tmp/mysql.sock" and restarted the server, but still the developed webpage (say page.html) does not load the info from the database. Then I found out that the php page (get.php) which is called by page.html (using a jquery ajax call $.get()) does work when I directly load get.php in the webbrowser (for that I added an 'echo' line and var_dump() of the info from the database).

Comment: UPDATE: PROBLEM SOLVED; as already indicated in my previous comment I found out that my first conclusion was wrong in the sense that my problem was not caused by a config issue with the software upgrade. The cause of the problem was  a coding 'error' (defined a constant twice) in a related developed php file (used by get.php) which obviously was ignored by the php 5.3 version but not by the 5.4. version